# How do I generate a series of hourly averages in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got data in ten minutes intervals in my table:

```
2009-01-26 00:00:00      12
2009-01-26 00:10:00      1.1
2009-01-26 00:20:00      11
2009-01-26 00:30:00      0
2009-01-26 00:40:00      5
2009-01-26 00:50:00      3.4
2009-01-26 01:00:00      7
2009-01-26 01:10:00      7
2009-01-26 01:20:00      7.2
2009-01-26 01:30:00      3
2009-01-26 01:40:00      25
2009-01-26 01:50:00      4
2009-01-26 02:00:00      3
2009-01-26 02:10:00      4
etc.
```

Is it possible to formulate a single SQL-query for MySQL which will return a series of averages over each hour?

In this case it should return:

```
5.42
8.87
etc.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's unclear whether you want the average to be aggregated over days or not.

If you want a different average for midnight on the 26th vs midnight on the 27th, then modify Mabwi's query thus:

```
SELECT AVG( value ) , thetime
FROM hourly_averages
GROUP BY DATE( thetime ), HOUR( thetime )
```

Note the additional `DATE()` in the `GROUP BY` clause.  Without this, the query would average together all of the data from `00:00` to `00:59` without regard to the date on which it happened.

Comment: How would one get the average data from every TWO hours?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
SELECT AVG( value ) , thetime
FROM hourly_averages
GROUP BY HOUR( thetime )
```

Here's the result

```
AVG(value)          thetime
5.4166666865349     2009-01-26 00:00:00
8.8666666348775     2009-01-26 01:00:00
3.5                 2009-01-26 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another possibility considering the fact that dates have a string representation in the database:

You can use `SUBSTRING(thetime, 1, [len])`, extracting the common part of your group. For the example with hourly averages you have the SQL query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(thetime, 1, 13) AS hours, AVG(value) FROM hourly_averages GROUP BY hours
```

By the `len` parameter you can specify the aggregated time interval considering the MySQL date format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SS...]`:

- `len = 4`: group by years
- `len = 7`: group by months
- `len = 10`: group by days
- `len = 13`: group by hours
- `len = 16`: group by minutes
- `len = 19`: group by seconds

We encountered a better performance of this method over using date and time function, especially when used in JOINs in MySQL 5.7. However in MySQL 8 at least for grouping both ways seem to take approximately the same time.